# Logged into Ubuntu as domain user, asks for first local user password on admin tasks

Tags: ubuntu, domain, gnome

I have an odd issue that happens on all of the Ubuntu machines I join to my Samba4 domain.

When installing, I create a user named `user` and then use that user to get the domain going. Everything goes smoothly after domain join, and I can login with `first.last` and `password` to the machine.

However, when logged in, if I try an administrative action in GNOME, such as opening a VPN for all users, it asks for the password for `user` vs `first.last` (or even `root`). How can I adjust this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gnome uses [PolKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) for authorization checks. By default `root` and the group `sudo` is considered as admins.

You just need to add `first.last` to the `sudo` group:

```
adduser first.last sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact adding domain users in sudoers is not enought as it will ask for local admin account for administrative tasks such as installing packages throught the GUI. It's not convenient to do everything in sudo command line.

So you have to edit the **etc/group** file and add the domain user in the "adm" group just like that :

adm:x:4:syslog,somelocaladmin,domain.user@domain.local